# How twitter bootstrap reduce tab character width in their code examples?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I didn't find anything in similar questions answers. It seems they didn't use tab-size preoprty and any special span blocks or spaces to immitate tabs.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: The answer is very simple: they don't use tabs. They use spaces. Tabs are not reliable as you have already figured out because their width can vary depending on browser.

Comment: Yep, now i see that there is cpaces. I didn't think that spaces could be copied as tabs. It seems code editor has converted them, so i saw spaces as tab character.